# Unable to login and no error message

Tags: php, authentication

I want to login, but I can't. The registration of users and passwords is ok but when I try to login nothing happens and no error message.

This is the code in my index.php:

```
<?php
require_once("config.php");
if (isset($_SESSION['username']) === FALSE){
header('location:login.php');
exit();
}
$where = "";
$sql = "SELECT id,subject FROM notes LIMIT 30";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
?>
```

---

And this is the code for login.php file:

```
<?php
require_once("config.php");
$message = '';
$username = '';
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {
$username = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['username']));
$password = sha1($_POST['password']);

$sql = "SELECT * from users 
where username ='" . $username . "' 
and password = '" . $password . "'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
$_SESSION['username'] = $username;
header("location:index.php");
} else {
$message = "Unable to login.  Check your username and password and try again.";
}
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form method ="POST" action="login.php">
<?php
if ($message != '') {
echo $message;
}
?>
<table>
<tr>
<th>username</th>
<td><input type="text" name="username" value ="<?php echo $username; ?>"/>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>password</th>
<td><input type="password" name="password" />
</tr>
</table>
<input type="submit" value="Login"/> &nbsp; <a href="registration.php"> register </a>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: does it redeirect to the index.php page?

Comment: yes, it redirects to the index.php file.

Comment: if so than its working correct, now add echo "Hello, World"; in index.php

Comment: @user2421425 **You are missing >** `session_start();` < this needs to be at the top and inside of **every file used**, underneath `<?php`. < **As answer?** You are using **sessions**, try my suggestion and then come back with your results.

Comment: @Fred that is correct unless he already called session_start() in config.php

Comment: @JosephPersie **True,** yet why do the OP's not make any mention of that, I'll never know. That's why it's the first question I always ask if there is no mention of it, nor included in posted code. **"Classic"**, seen it way too often, enough to make my head spin, *really*.

Comment: @user2421425 Have you tried what I suggested yet? I'm about to give up here and move on to another question.

Comment: sorry, I have been trying, but with session_start(); it takes me directly to the index.php without login

Comment: >[**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer* maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: Many thanks for your recommendation. Finally it was my fault. It worked with session_start();. Sorry.

Comment: @user2421425 My suggestion should've been made as an answer to start with. I knew **I was right.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cant reply on the post since i have no rep, but there we go:

"sorry, I have been trying, but with session_start(); it takes me directly to the index.php without login – user2421425 1 min ago"

Its because you are loged in, try to create a logout.php with:

```
<?
session_start();
session_destroy();
header('location:index.php');
?>
```

Hope it help

Comment: I already had a logout.php file, but it was my mistake. Now it is solved. Many thanks.